# Regex to extract font family in a sass file

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6, sass

Probably extremely obvious but I don't really get along with regex...

I am trying to extract the font name from a sass file containing a @font-face in javascript. The example would be the following:

Given this string:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'fancy-icons';
    src:
        url('#{$icon-font-path}/fancy-icons.ttf?p3owtd') format('truetype'),
        url('#{$icon-font-path}/fancy-icons.woff?p3owtd') format('woff'),
        url('#{$icon-font-path}/fancy-icons.svg?p3owtd#fancy-icons') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I want to extract the word `fancy-icons`, meaning the string within the single quotes and it could be anything.

The closes attempt led me to this code:

```
const scssContent = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('fonts.scss'), 'utf-8');
scssContent.match(new RegExp(/font-family: '(.*?)';/g));
```

but all I am getting is the whole `font-family: 'fancy-icons';`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression)

Comment: Your regex is fine. You just need to access the proper capture group. I'd suggest using `font-family:\s*'([^']*)'` instead, but your regex is still fine.

Comment: Forgot to say `font-family: 'fancy-icons';` is the only matching group I am getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Brief

As I mentioned in the comments below your question, you simply need to access the first capture group. I'm not sure what code you're using in JavaScript, but below is a snippet that performs the suggested edit I made as well as some minor adjustments to your regex to improve performance (using `[^']*` instead of `.*?`).

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/hFyguA/1/)

```
font-family:\s*'([^']*)'
```

#### Usage

```js
var s = `@font-face {
    font-family: 'fancy-icons';
    src:
        url('#{$icon-font-path}/fancy-icons.ttf?p3owtd') format('truetype'),
        url('#{$icon-font-path}/fancy-icons.woff?p3owtd') format('woff'),
        url('#{$icon-font-path}/fancy-icons.svg?p3owtd#fancy-icons') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}`;

var r = /font-family:\s*'([^']*)'/g;
var m = r.exec(s);
while(m != null) {
  console.log(m[1]);
  m = r.exec(s);
}
```

---

### Explanation

- `font-family:` Match this literally
- `\s*` Match any number of whitespace characters
- `'` Match the apostrophe character literally
- `([^']*)` Capture any character except the apostrophe character any number of times into capture group 1
- `'` Match the apostrophe character literally

Comment: Don't ask me why but it wasn't working with `match` on the sass string read from the file with node. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that:

```js
const arr = [
  `font-family:'xxx';`,
  `font-family:'xxx'`,
  `font-family: 'xxx';`,
  `font-family: "xxx";`,
  `font-family:"xxx";`
];

arr.forEach(str => console.log(str.match(/font\-family:\s*['"]([^"']+)['"];?/)))
```